# Firefox sessionstore.bak: 4000 kb but empty

Tags: firefox

My Firefox session crashed, and when I restarted it, the `Restore previous session` menu option was greyed out.  I found the `sessionstore.bak` file (the `.js` version had been written over, since I'd opened Firefox again).

The new `sessionstore.js` file is 1 kb, and the JSON shows that the only tab was the Firefox Start Page.  The `.bak` file is 3476 kb (implying it should have all the info from the last session), but it seems to be empty when I open it in a text editor. Is there a way to recover the info?

**Update**

Actually, viewing the file as Unicode shows contents, but just as thousands of identical unicode(?) symbols: `�` my knowledge of character encoding doesn't go far enough to know how to deal with this! I'd assume this means it *isn't* unicode, but is there a way of decoding it (a hint to a python way would be amazingly helpful!)

Comment: To recover what can be recovered, [backup your profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles) first.

Comment: @and31415 I know about how profile _normally_ works, but that doesn't seem to have happened in my case; I've updated my question to reflect this

Comment: I was just pointing out that using a broken profile will increase the chances something else might be overwritten. That's why it's important to backup it. Open the file using a hexadecimal editor (e.g. [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) and post an excerpt of the actual file content.